# When does SqlDataSource populate control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a webform with a `sqldatasource` that populates a `DropDownList`. The webform's `Page_Load` reads from that `DropDownList`.

It seems that the values are not present in the `DropDownList` when `Page_Load` executes; `DropDownList.Items.Count` equals 0 during Page_Load.

So when exactly is the dropdown populated? I know I can populate it in the codebehind, but I prefer using `sqldatasource`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1488957.aspx?DropdownList%20box%20is%20empty%20on%20Page_Load%20event) helped me out.

At `Page_Load`, the `SqlDataSource` control hasn't been bound. Just call `DropDownList.DataBind()` before I access the control.